# The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conda

While installing Tensorflow came across this error. Can anyone help to resolve this issue?.
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:[image]

I am using python 3.7, condo version 4.5.12,  MACOS High Seirra v.10.13.4

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded python 3.7 to python 3.6 by typing command in terminal

```
condo install python=3.6
```

then installed tensor flow.

```
Pip Install Tensorflow
```

restarted Jupyter notebook and it worked.